Svg fold in vs code
Classes can be fold as Flowed. Many classes can be accommodated in a small space. Is it possible to keep SVG like this? Or are there any extensions for vs code?
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="..." viewBox="..." fill="currentColor"> <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="..." clip-rule="evenodd" /> </svg>
I couldn't find it. I'm very upset with SVG. Let me know if anyone knows

See the duplicate - I added an answer there with an Inline Fold setting that specifically handles your request.
